# Scrapy - Disable Selenium after first request

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm scraping urls from a site but only the first request needs of selenium and the other don't. Is it possible to turn off Selenium in the middle of scrap process? I want do that, because, as you probably now, Selenium slows down a lot the scrap process. This is the code for the Spider:

```
class StoreSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'store'
    allowed_domains = ['www.store.com.br']
    custom_settings = {
        'COLLECTION_NAME'   : 'store',
        'URLS_COLLECTION_NAME'   : 'store_urls',
        'USES_SELENIUM'          : True,
        'HEADLESS'               : True,
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
            'navigator.middlewares.SeleniumMiddleware': 700,
        }
    }

    categories_le = LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//li[@class='h3']/a[not(@id)]")

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.store.com.br/loja/mapa-do-site',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_categories)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your middleware so that it only uses Selenium when the request comes with a `render_js` meta key.

Something like this:

```
class SeleniumMiddleware(object):
    ...
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if not request.meta.get('render_js'):
            # disable js rendering in a per-request basis
            return

        # render with selenium
        ...
```

This works because when a downloader middleware's `process_request` returns `None`, the request will proceed to the next middlewares in the chain, eventually hitting Scrapy's downloader.

More info here: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_request